# Passing functions to d3 generators in typescript

Tags: d3.js, typescript

I'm converting some code from d3v3 javascript to d3v4 typescript
In d3v3javascript it looks like the following.

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.startAngle(function(d) {
    return d.x;
})
```

However when I try to convert it to d3v4 typescript I do the following

```
arc = D3.arc()
.startAngle(( d) => {
    return d.x;
})
```

Property x does not exist on type  'DefaultArcObject'

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems that `DefaultArcObject` does not have a built-in `x` property. You can either manually add it to it's  `d.ts` (not recommended) or just give `d` the `any` type.

```
arc = D3.arc()
.startAngle(( d: any ) => {
    return d.x;
})
```